# Pop up doesn't center on the marker on first click but does on 2nd click, 3rd, etc

Tags: leaflet, popup

I'm am very new to all of this so it could be something fairly obvious.

I'm using leaflet to create markers on a map and when you click the marker a popup with an image shows up. However I'm having the issue of the popup (first time clicking) doesn't center the popup over the marker, instead the bottom left corner of the marker goes over the marker. However, if I click a marker that has already been clicked before the page will move and the pop up will become centered over the marker as desired.

Here is what I have done:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>TEST</title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css"
      integrity="sha256-p4NxAoJBhIIN+hmNHrzRCf9tD/miZyoHS5obTRR9BMY="
      crossorigin=""
    />
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js"
      integrity="sha256-20nQCchB9co0qIjJZRGuk2/Z9VM+kNiyxNV1lvTlZBo="
      crossorigin=""
    ></script>

    <style>
      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .leaflet-container {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
      }

      .leaflet-popup-content {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        width: auto !important; /* Set width to auto */
        max-width: 100%; /* Ensure the content does not exceed the available width */
      }

      .leaflet-popup-content img {
        max-width: 60vw;
        max-height: 45vw;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      const map = L.map("map").setView([54.5, -107.09], 6);

      L.tileLayer("https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
        attribution:
          '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org  /copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
      }).addTo(map);

      var marker = L.marker([74.697, -94.83], {
        title: "title",
      })
        .addTo(map)
        .bindPopup('<img src="https://examplewebsite.com/images/image1.png">');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```